# Query not returning anything when no last_name value found

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, ifnull

I just built this new conditional query for pulling either a `first_name` AND `last_name` OR `company_name` based on the `display_as` value:

```
Select If(`display_as` = 'individual',
    CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)
   ,`company_name`) as name FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `unique_id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

The problem is, if the user has a `first_name` value only and `no value` for `last_name`, nothing is returned at all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: This happens because any operation involving a NULL and a NOT NULL value results to NULL, with the exception of IFNULL and COALESCE, which are used to address the issue by providing a default value in case of NULL. The answers given are typical examples of the functions usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this query instead.

```
$sql = "Select If(`display_as` = 'individual',
    CONCAT(IFNULL(first_name, ''), ' ', IFNULL(last_name, ''))
   ,`company_name`) as name FROM `{$this->table}` WHERE `unique_id` = ? LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I would personally surround the CONCAT() expression with a TRIM() to remove trailing spaces in case of NULL.

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
Select
    If( `display_as` = 'individual',
        CONCAT(coalesce(first_name, ''), ' ', coalesce(last_name, ''))
       ,`company_name`) as name
FROM `{$this->table}`
WHERE `unique_id` = ?
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
select (case when display_as = 'individual' 
             then concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name)
             else company_name
        end) as name 
from `{$this->table}` 
where unique_id = ?
limit 1;  -- probably not needed
```

Notes:

- `case` is the standard SQL construct for conditional logic.  `if()` is a bespoke MySQL extension.
- `concat_ws()` elegantly handles `NULL` values in the names.  It simply ignores the the value rather than returning `NULL`.
- Backticks are not required everywhere.  They just make the query harder to write and read.
- If your `unique_id` is really unique, you don't need `LIMIT 1`.